# Flutter AutoRoute Cannot GET /login

Tags: navigation, flutter-web

I am developing a Flutter Web app. For the navigation, I use AutoRoute.

Those are my routes:

```
@CustomAutoRouter(
  replaceInRouteName: 'Screen,Route',
  transitionsBuilder: TransitionsBuilders.noTransition,
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    AutoRoute(
      page: SplashScreen,
      initial: true,
      path: "/",
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      page: LoginScreen,
      path: "/login",
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      page: SignupScreen,
      path: "/signup",
    ),
  ],
)
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {}
```

Now, when I run the app locally in Chrome and I type in the URL http://localhost:/login, I get navigated directly to the LoginScreen, as it is supposed to be.
Although when I build the app and deploy it to a Web Server (in my case Azure Cloud, if that is important), I can't navigate with the URL. I can only navigate to the initial route and from there on navigate within the app. But when I type int baseUrl/login, I see the following (no matter whether with or without query params):

[image: Login Screen error]

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
Maybe that is important: I am running the app in a node.js server